# Unknown column ' IS NULL LIMIT 15' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting an database error i.e `Error Number: 1054`

Unknown column `' IS NULL LIMIT 15'` in 'where clause'
`SELECT * FROM (categories) WHERE IS NULL LIMIT 15`

```
function categories()
{   

    $this->suri=3;
    $this->surl=site_url('variables/categories/');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $cond = array(
                'parent_id' => '0'
                );
    $config['base_url'] = $this->surl;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->commonmodel->getcountcond('categories',$cond);
    $config['per_page'] = '15';
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span>';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
    $config['uri_segment'] = $this->suri; 
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $parent_cond = array(
                'parent_id' => '0'
                 );
```

Comment: Its very clear from the error you are getting. You are missing the column name from your query.

Comment: i have all these fields present in my table...

Comment: Which db field are you checking for NULL?

Comment: Well tahnks guys..... there was mistake in my controllers function and also in my specifiede field....

Comment: It ahd to be "categories.parent_id" but i was writing only "categories"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query must be: 
you must have a reference field in your where clause

```
SELECT * FROM (categories) WHERE `categories.field` IS NULL LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->commonmodel->getcountcond('categories',$cond);
```

This counter doesn't work.. check it ;)